# Mouse Event BHO

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, atl, mouseevent, bho

I want my BHO to listen to onmousedown event of some element in a certain webpage.
I have all the code that find the specific element, and in msdn its says that I need to use the [get_onmousedown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752318(VS.85).aspx) event. I came up with this code.

```
 CComQIPtr<IHTMLElement> someElement;
 VARIANT mouse_eve;
 someElement->get_onmousedown(&mouse_eve);
```

The question is, how do I tell it to run some function when this event occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `v` - VARIANT of type VT_DISPATCH that specifies the IDispatch interface of an object with a default method that is invoked when the event occurs.

Event handlers in this context are COM instances that implement `IDispatch` - so you need to pass a pointer to an `IDispatch` that your event handler object implements:

```
CComQIPtr<IDispatch> spDisp(spMyHandler); // something like that
someElement->put_onmousedown(CComVariant(spDisp));
```

*Note: `put_` instead of `get_` - you want to register a handler*.

On this, [`IDispatch::Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221479(VS.85).aspx) gets called with:

- `wFlags` containing `DISPATCH_METHOD` (*"a method is getting invoked"*)
- `dispIdMember` being `0` / `DISPID_VALUE` (*"the default method"*)

Put together this should become something like:

```
HRESULT MyHandler::Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID, LCID, WORD wFlags, 
                          DISPPARAMS*, VARIANT*, EXCEPINFO*, UINT*)
{
    // ...

    if((wFlags & DISPATCH_METHOD) && (dispIdMember == DISPID_VALUE)) 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't let me to add "MainClassName::Invoke" as a function:  "overriding virtual function differs from 'ATL::IDispatchImpl<T,piid,plibid,wMajor,wMinor>::Invoke' only by calling convention"

Comment: Use `HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke(/* params */)` or `STDMETHOD(Invoke)(/* params */)` for the declaration.

Comment: Thank you! one last question: in the invoke method, how do I use the current IDispatch?

Comment: I think I understand, but the only reason I wanted the mouse event is to get the changes on the page when someone clicks on something. and I need to get an IHTMLDocument2 object.

Comment: I see, i somehow saw a different question there. But you can always register custom event listener objects that have access to the document you need?